# Poor response times office 365 REST API

Tags: ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm using the new office REST APIs in order to access Exchange data, the APIs are behaving as expected however the response times of the requests are hugely variable.

Below are the times recorder over 30 requests with a 10 second interval between each (all requests return the same data):

```
I: Polling request time: 33428ms
I: Polling request time: 35979ms
I: Polling request time: 5247ms
I: Polling request time: 28293ms
I: Polling request time: 5362ms
I: Polling request time: 5556ms
I: Polling request time: 5495ms
I: Polling request time: 27744ms
I: Polling request time: 1161ms
I: Polling request time: 34227ms
I: Polling request time: 865ms
I: Polling request time: 32169ms
I: Polling request time: 542ms
I: Polling request time: 5872ms
I: Polling request time: 641ms
I: Polling request time: 29248ms
I: Polling request time: 4756ms
I: Polling request time: 27813ms
I: Polling request time: 8048ms
I: Polling request time: 28107ms
I: Polling request time: 934ms
I: Polling request time: 29112ms
I: Polling request time: 29216ms
I: Polling request time: 5511ms
I: Polling request time: 1805ms
I: Polling request time: 33739ms
I: Polling request time: 8836ms
I: Polling request time: 1466ms
I: Polling request time: 31531ms
I: Polling request time: 30088ms
I: Polling request time: 333ms
I: Polling request time: 6271ms
I: Polling request time: 1670ms
```

**Average time:** 16.4 seconds -
**Maximum time:** 35.9 seconds

Occasionally the requests time out.

Is this a known issue and are the response times expected to improve? Has anyone else experienced poor response times?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I can only confirm with a limited number of **SOAP** (not REST) test cases that yes, Office 365 is slow. I'm doing synchronization with Exchange Server and locally it screams in comparison with Office365. But that is to be expected with all those small data packets travelling halfway across the world to a busy MS server. I have not timed individual request though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your mail and the detailed test results!  This is a known issue impacting our REST API endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0 and a fix is on its way by end of year.  A temporary workaround is to use our Preview endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/ as this preview endpoint isn't impacted by the same issue.

Sorry again for the inconvenience and please let me know if you see the latency spikes with https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/ODATA/ as well.

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Venkat, the preview endpoint seems a lot more stable, all request are sub 500ms. Is there anything I should be aware of when using this preview over the production one? Thanks again for your help Venkat.

Comment: Hi Nick, Nothing to worry about. We are looking to fix the performance spikes you have reported with the production endpoint soon, and will provide an update when the deployment is completed.  At that time, please switch to the production endpoint.  Hope that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this? It seems performance is still poor on the production API.

Comment: Nick - The first set of fixes have been deployed and that is showing improved response times per our measurements.  Another set of fixes is in the works.  Is there a specific request or all requests where you see poor performance?  Is this sporadic or consistent?  If you can share any details, we can investigate in case you are facing a performance issue we aren't tracking.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT I'm having extremely slow response times for the Office 365 Outlook endpoints as well. What's going on?

Comment: Nick - We have been making multiple fixes.  Are you seeing the latency hit sporadically, with a specific request, or with all requests.  Can you please provide the raw request and response with all the headers, so we can take a look?  Thanks.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSF, sorry to say but I think many developers are going to look for alternative solutions to 365 considering this api response problem has been going on for longer than 6 months. I am not sure how things are at Microsoft but a serious bug like this should not wait 6 months to fix. I created 120 new events using the api which took in total about 18min which to me is ridiculous.

Comment: Hi Karol, Sorry to hear that.  We have seen improvements in the latencies per our metrics and would like to investigate your specific issue.  Can you please contact me @VRAyyadevara on Twitter and we can take it from there?